# Why is spring form not reading my customer bean?

Tags: java, spring, validation, spring-mvc

I have been doing a udemy course and one of the projects was to create a string (which is the postal code) within the customer object and use regular expressions to display the postal code. But for some reason whenever I go to the page, I get the following error:

[image: Error Page]

The form should load up and I should be able to enter the properties.

I have copied and pasted the code from the course and it still didn't work.

I can give you the code here:

```
public class Customer {
private String firstName;

@NotNull(message="is required")
@Size(min=1, message="is required")
private String lastName;

@Min(value=0, message="must be greater than or equal to zero")
@Max(value=10, message="must be less than or equal to 10")
private int freePasses;

@Pattern(regexp="^[a-zA-Z0-9]{5}", message="only 5 chars/digits")
private String postalCode;
//Getters and setters after here
```

And the code for the form as well:

```
 <%@ taglib prefix="form" uri="http://www.springframework.org/tags/form" %>

<html>

<head>
    <title>Customer Registration Form</title>

    <style>
        .error {color:red}
    </style>
</head>
<body>

<i>Fill out the form. Asterisk (*) means required.</i>
<br><br>

    <form:form action="processForm" modelAttribute="customer">

        First name: <form:input path="firstName" />

        <br><br>

        Last name (*): <form:input path="lastName" />
        <form:errors path="lastName" cssClass="error" />

        <br><br>

        Free passes: <form:input path="freePasses" />
        <form:errors path="freePasses" cssClass="error" />

        <br><br>

        Postal Code: <form:input path="postalCode" />
        <form:errors path="postalCode" cssClass="error" />

        <br><br>

        <input type="submit" value="Submit" />

    </form:form>

</body>

</html>
```

I had this error before when I was working on a earlier part of the lesson, but copy and paste fixed it.

Thanks in regards.

Comment: Could you share all your jsp code?

Comment: Yeah.I can make and edit real fast

Comment: Did u find the problem?

Comment: Provide full code from Customer class and spring configuration. Jsp seems like correct

Comment: And Controller code that handles this request

Comment: I asked my udemy instructor and he said that the code was running fine on his computer, and he said to try and remove the build folder

Comment: it didnt work though